# Django Access Foreign Key Table's Data in InlineFormset_Factory

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am using formsets to create a feedback page but I am not able to access foreign key table values in django template.

I have this models below that are for a feedback system.

Models.py

```
class FeedbackForm(amdl.AagamBaseModel):
    feedback_form_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    subject_teacher = models.ForeignKey(MapMySchoolUserSubject, models.DO_NOTHING)
    feedback_form_date = models.DateField()
    feedback_form_status = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'feedback_form'

class FeedbackFormQuestion(amdl.AagamBaseModel):
    feedback_form_question_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    feedback_form = models.ForeignKey('FeedbackForm', models.DO_NOTHING)
    feedback_question = models.ForeignKey('FeedbackQuestion', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'feedback_form_question'

class Feedback(amdl.AagamBaseModel):
    feedback_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    feedback_form_question = models.ForeignKey('FeedbackFormQuestion', models.DO_NOTHING)
    map_myschool_user_standard_section = models.ForeignKey(MapMySchoolUserStandardSection, models.DO_NOTHING)
    feedback_rating = models.IntegerField()
    feedback_comments = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    feedback_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'feedback'

class FeedbackQuestion(amdl.AagamBaseModel):
    feedback_question_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    question_text = models.TextField()
    feedback_question_credit = models.IntegerField()
    question_group = models.ForeignKey('FeedbackQuestionGroup', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'feedback_question'

class FeedbackQuestionGroup(amdl.AagamBaseModel):
    feedback_question_group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    question_group = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'feedback_question_group'
```

The `Feedback` model is the main model where the rating of feedback is given by students. As the rating is per question there is one row per question that is in foreign key with the `FeedbackFormQuestion` which is the relationship (many-to-many) between `FeedbackForm` and `FeedbackQuestion` that make up a feedback form. Other models are just for analysis and graphs.

This is the view where there is a formset for the Model and it is based on a `FORM` (shown bafter view.py) that manages the looks in html. Need formset for handling multiple forms with MySchoolUSer data to be same for all.
View.py

```
def aagam_feedback(request):
    model_formset = inlineformset_factory(MapMySchoolUserStandardSection, Feedback, fields=('feedback_form_question','feedback_rating','feedback_comments'), form=FormFeedback, can_delete=False)                                  
    stud_nav = views.student_navbar(request)
    stud = MapMySchoolUserStandardSection.objects.get(pk=stud_nav['standard_section_current']['pk'])
    formset = model_formset(queryset=Feedback.objects.none(), instance=stud, initial=[{'feedback_form_question': 4}, {'feedback_form_question': 4}])

    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = model_formset(request.POST, instance=stud)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect("/")

    return render(request, 'StudentFeedback/aagam_feedback.html', {'formset': formset})
```

form.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from StudentFeedback import models


class FormFeedback(ModelForm):
    CHOICES = [(1, ''),
               (2, ''),
               (3, ''),
               (4, ''),
               (5, '')]
    feedback_rating = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), label=False, label_suffix=False)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Feedback
        fields = ['feedback_form_question', 'feedback_rating', 'feedback_comments']
```

This is the html but i am not able to access this data form foreign key table
.html

```
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        // Want to access the question_text below but it is blank.
        {{ form.feedback_form_question.feedback_question.question_text }}
        {% for rating in form.feedback_rating %}
            {{ rating }}
        {% endfor %}
        {{ form.feedback_comments }}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-12" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false">
</form>
```

#### output

[image: output]

#### Expected output

[image: expected output]

I have used accessed foreign key data like this many times but not sure why it is not coming here.

Comment: I don't know, if I really got your error but try it with OneToOneField: 
There are multiple types of Foreignkey in Django:
- OnetoOneField
- OnetoManyField
- ForeignField

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Comment: @Henrik  in html page i am not able to get the foreign key value with this `{{ form.feedback_form_question.feedback_question.question_text }}`. I want the value of question_text field.

Comment: Why don't you write `{{ form.feedback_form_question }}` if you want to render the field? Or do you **not** want to give the choice to the user and just display which question it is for?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I just want display the question. User has to only give rating and comment. User cannot edit or change the question

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I am finding that `form.instance` is not working. Is it because of the initial values provided to the form are not model instances but just a dict() of some non model instance values? `initial=[{'feedback_form_question': 4}, {'feedback_form_question': 4}]`. Should i give it a try? Also thanks for the help. that too Twice in a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to allow the user to select the question just make the field disabled on your form:

```py
class FormFeedback(ModelForm):
    CHOICES = [(1, ''),
               (2, ''),
               (3, ''),
               (4, ''),
               (5, '')]
    feedback_rating = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), label=False, label_suffix=False)
    feedback_form_question = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=FeedbackFormQuestion.objects.all(),
        disabled=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = models.Feedback
        fields = ['feedback_form_question', 'feedback_rating', 'feedback_comments']
```

Now in your form instead of writing `{{ form.feedback_form_question.feedback_question.question_text }}` which really doesn't make sense as `form.feedback_form_question` is a **form field** not the value stored for that field. Instead since now we simply have our field as disabled go ahead and render the field (Even if the user tampers with the html it won't be taken by the form). Also whenever dealing with forms one should **always** remember to render the hidden fields, more so in the case of formsets which add several important hidden fields:

```
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        <!-- Render the hidden fields -->
        {% for field in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
        <!-- Render the field -->
        {{ form.feedback_form_question }}
        {% for rating in form.feedback_rating %}
            {{ rating }}
        {% endfor %}
        {{ form.feedback_comments }}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-12" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false">
</form>
```

You can override the `__str__` of your model to modify what is displayed:

```py
class FeedbackFormQuestion(amdl.AagamBaseModel):
    # Your implementation
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.feedback_question.question_text
```

Comment: I am still getting this `{{ form.instance.feedback_form_question.feedback_question.question_text }}` column blank.

Comment: @AagamSheth try `{{ form.instance.feedback_form_question }}` instead. What does that give you?

Comment: @AagamSheth remove the hidden input part and simply render the field. Check my edit.

Comment: Yes it is rendering.

Comment: But is still not the output i need. The ouput is in `question_text` field of model and the display i sof feedback_form_question

Comment: You should define the `__str__` method of your `FeedbackFormQuestion` to return an appropriate representation that you want to be displayed.